# Is it possible to set Air View functionalities?

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

Some of the Samsung devices have an option called Air View which let's you hold your hand or finger above the screen and you can do different things such as viewing an extra discription or other things. Here's a full discription about Air View:

androidcentral.com/what-airview-galaxy-s5-and-what-it-can-do-you

So I was wondering is there any way to have this functionality in my app (for example holding your finger above a button and a discription/tooltip appears) and if so, how do you do it; or is it exclusively for apps made by Samsung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Samsung devices you can add it to your app to use:
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=QTh1VGyQR5l2Xhc123VNprtfWk5zQHqTfZPNcmGqV5nbk5sBK5HS!-1892717541?v=T000000023

Comment: After I add the <intent-filter> should I add an OnHoverListener or something?